# chat application, peer-to-peer communication

Tags: p2p

I am in the process of developing a chat application using Javascript.  When sending messages from one client to another client, do I have to send it through a server or can I send it directly from a peer-to-peer approach, using something like websockets ?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the stage of life where you see the importance of design patterns.

You can start solutionizing with mediator pattern and proxy pattern with web sockets.
Wheater you need a server or not is up to your design.
Technology-wise there are multiple APIs that HTML5 offers you can go through them and make something on your own.
There is a bunch of APIs available with HTML5 and JS. 
Start digging on WebSockets, Server-Sent Events, Web Workers.

The server will give you the flexibility of record-keeping while acting as a mediator. Alternatively, you can come up with a pure p2p design with a scheme where every node or user notify other users with their details(IP) for establishing communication. Remember for web socket to work the client need to know what address to connect to. Maybe it can have fixed master nodes. Then you can use observables for polling and other features. Take a look at the BitTorrent protocol for design inspiration.

Get creative and start designing.

Comment: Study the design patterns and decide if you want to go for a server (centralized design),  distributed design or a hybrid. If you have less time, a centralized design is easiest to pull off.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. I recommend the scheme:

```
Peer <---> custom websocket server <---> Peer;
```

I recommend [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) with [SocketIO](https://socket.io/).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers everyone, I read a bit of articles on the this, and trying to figure out the role of the web server.  From my understanding the web server will get a message from one client and then push it to the destination client (putting it mildly)?